# Reusing the step names in cucumber gherkin

Tags: java, cucumber, reusability, gherkin

I am using cucumber gherkin with java. Here as per our requirements, I need to reuse the steps across scenarios in my feature file.
For example, I have below two scenarios in my feature file.

Scenario: View Item

- Given user logged in with valid credentials
- When user search for a item with name
- Then item is shown in the Summary
- And item price is visible to user

Scenario: Edit Item

- Given user logged in with valid credentials
- When user search for a item with name
- And chooses an item for edit
- Then item becomes editable to user
- And item price is visible to user

Here, the steps, "user search for a item with name", "item price is visible to user" is repeating which is very valid for my tests.
But this is not accepted in cucumber gherkin. It says the error and it forces me to use the unique names for the steps.
Is there anyway I can reuse the steps in same feature file across scenarios?

One workaround is -
I need to define these two scenarios in different feature files, and need to use glue feature of cucumber to associate each feature file with separate java packages for step definitions (note: I can glue only java packages to a feature, not a class).

So, currently I am defining N number of feature files (separate feature file for each scenario), and same number of java packages.
This makes my test codebase too big, soon I may get into maintainability issue.

Comment: Is the step " item price is visible to user" is doing same action in both scenario?. What ever you are asking is normal behaviour in cucumber. You can reuse same step in multiple scenario in the same feature file or in the different feature file. Are you want to keep same name for two different step definitions?.

Answer (score 1):

Write duplicate steps when needed. Duplicated steps are sometimes needed to be able to create Gherkin that is interesting and relevant for your stakeholders. However, delegate to a helper method immediately in the steps. Your steps should just be one-liners.

The common behaviour you need is implemented in the helper methods and the duplication you think about will be reduced. It might be reduced so much that it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use duplicate steps as part of different scenarios in a single feature file. Moreover, there will be only single JAVA code required for the duplicate step in cucumber Gherkin.

Additionally, For common steps as part of a single feature file, You can use Background keyword as well and it will be executed before execution of each and every scenario. 
Example:

- Background:
- Given user logged in with valid credentials
- When user search for a item with name

And keep all scenarios a little lighter.

- Scenario: View Item
- Then item is shown in the Summary
- And item price is visible to user

And other Scenario:

- Scenario: Edit Item
- And chooses an item for edit
- Then item becomes editable to user
- And item price is visible to user

I hope it helps.